# onTouch event coordinates and imageview draw coordinates mismatch

Tags: android, events, canvas, imageview, touch-event

I have:

```
                    imageView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            //Choose which motion action has been performed
            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    //Get X, Y coordinates from the ImageView
                    int X = (int) event.getX();


                    int Y = (int) event.getY();
```

and

```
                        BitmapFactory.Options myOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                    myOptions.inDither = true;
                    myOptions.inScaled = false;
                    myOptions.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;// important
                    myOptions.inPurgeable = true;

                    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.lithuania,myOptions);
                    Paint paint = new Paint();
                    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
                    paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);


                    Bitmap workingBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap);
                    Bitmap mutableBitmap = workingBitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);


                    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(mutableBitmap);
                    canvas.drawCircle(40, 160, 15, paint);


                    imageView.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
                    imageView.setImageBitmap(mutableBitmap);
```

Any idea, how to make relation between those coordinates? Cause now my onTouch coordinates and drawing coordinates has to be different in order to represent it correctly to user.

Searched here, but seems no one have a correct answer. Any help will be appreciated :)

[image: red one is my finger]

**EDIT**

```
                    float xRatio = (float)bitmap.getWidth() / imageView.getWidth();
                    float xPos = event.getX() * xRatio;
                    float yPos = event.getY() * xRatio;

                    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(mutableBitmap);
                    canvas.drawCircle(xPos, yPos, 15, paint);
```

Working like a charm!

Comment: its not clear what you are trying to accomplish, where is touchX,touchY used?  I assume you are trying to place the circle at the touch location?  What is your touch listener attached to?

Comment: Yes, your assumption is correct. It is attached to imageview.

Comment: It is possible to get coordinates not of an screen, but image/imageview itself? So my (40, 160, 15, paint) coordinates would be same for user click event.

Comment: if the touchlistener is attached to the imageView your coordinates should be relative to the top-left of the imageView itself, how far off is your circle?

Comment: As @Shooky said, coordinates should already be referred to the internal coordinate system of the View. What's your goal?

Comment: Added ss, red one indicates my finger press. Also changed this:   `canvas.drawCircle(event.getX(), event.getY(), 15, paint);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have tested your code, the issue is that your bitmap has different dimensions then your imageView.  You need to determine the difference in sizes and adjust accordingly.  For example the image I used was 1800x1800 and my imageView was 900x900 so I had to multiple my X and Y coordinates by 2 to get the correct position

```
int xRatio = bitmap.getWidth() / imageView.getWidth();
int xPos = event.getX() * xRatio;
```

Here is a more robust version which takes into account bitmaps that are smaller then the target view:

```
            int xRatio, yRatio;
            int xPos, yPos;
            if (mutableBitmap.getWidth() >= ib.getWidth()) {
                xRatio = mutableBitmap.getWidth() / ib.getWidth();
                xPos = (int) Math.floor(xRatio * event.getX());
            } else {
                xRatio = ib.getWidth() / mutableBitmap.getWidth();
                xPos = (int) Math.floor(xRatio*event.getX()-((ib.getWidth() - mutableBitmap.getWidth())/2));
            }

            if (mutableBitmap.getHeight() >= ib.getHeight()) {
                yRatio = mutableBitmap.getHeight() / ib.getHeight();
                yPos = (int)Math.floor(event.getY()*yRatio);
            } else {
                yRatio = ib.getHeight() / mutableBitmap.getHeight();
                yPos = (int) Math.floor(yRatio*event.getY()-((ib.getHeight() - mutableBitmap.getHeight())/2));
            }
```

Comment: my image is 812x600, how I should adjust accordingly? My imageView has fill parent in both height and width